# Batch file to remove copied shortcuts from public desktop

Tags: batch-file, sccm, shortcut-file

I currently use this code to copy shortcuts from a folder on a server to C:\Users\Desktop:

```
if not exist "%1" md "%1"
copy /y "%~dp0PlaceShortcutsHere\*.*" "%1"
```

This copies any shortcuts I place in the folder to the desktop.

I now need a way to remove these, baring in mind that the shortcuts in the source folder can and will change over time.

Is there a way to compare the shortcuts in the desktop and on the server and only delete the ones that are present in both folders, and only from the desktop of the computer?

These shortcuts are not all of the shortcuts on the desktop of the machines, there are others as well, hence wanting to only delete the ones present in both locations. I will also need this to be adaptive as the shortcuts present on the server will be added to or removed as needed.

This is to be deployed out through SCCM 2007/12 but I want to test it locally first.

And yes, using a GP would be easier but the GP we use has stopped working so I need a backup way of deploying shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Took some time but I've found an answer myself. Posting this if it is useful to anyone in the future.

```
dir "%~dp0PlaceShortcutsHere\*" /a /b /-p /o:gen>>"%~dp0ShortcutList_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt"
Pushd \\<Server>\<Share>
for /F "delims=" %%G in (ShortcutList_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt) DO Del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\%%G"
del "%~dp0ShortcutList_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt"
```

Breaking it down:

```
dir "%~dp0PlaceShortcutsHere\*" /a /b /-p /o:gen>>"%~dp0ShortcutList_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt"
```

The above created a text file with the names of the shortcuts in it for referencing by the next line.

```
Pushd \\<Server>\<Share>
for /F "delims=" %%G in (ShortcutList_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt) DO Del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\%%G"
```

The above maps the server/share that the files are in temporarily, then uses the "For /F" loop to get the file names and then delete them.

```
del "%~dp0ShortcutList_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt"
```

Finally, this line deleted the text file that was created.

This is useful for when the contents of the folder is always changing, it will create an up to date list of the files and then delete the list afterwards, preventing confusion.

```
%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%
```

Lastly, this little line will input the current date into the filename of the text documet, so should the final delete line not work you can see the date on it. At a guess I would also think that putting it in paths will make the script only choose the files from the current day, not any others, but I have not tested this.

Please correct me if I'm wrong on anything.